# flexslider появляется текст за текстом

Tags: css

Делаю слайдер на [лендинге](http://uclend.kkulakov.ru/) на flexslider. Абсолютно не разбираюсь в jquery.

При прокрутке слайдера, на активном слайде, средствами css делается жирным фамилия и имя автора комментарии, однако под жирным текстом остаются прежнего размера буквы. Правда не везде. Пробовал убирать все настройки css с активного слайдера не помогло. Грешу на неправильную обработку jquery слайдера, но там да же не знаю где смотреть. Вроде в css ничего дублирующего нет.

Вот так это выглядит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код активного слайда:

```
.flex-active-slide .autor-name h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold", ProximaNovaBold, sans-serif;
}
</code>
Код в стандартном режиме:
<code>
.autor-name h1 {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova", ProximaNova, sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: В каком браузере тестируете сайт? Ни в IE10 ни в FF41 ошибка не воспроизводится.

Comment: Вчера подобная проблема была попробуйте добавить: `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Comment: В хроме. Версия последняя.

Comment: -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; не помог

Comment: Видимо действительно проблема в обработке браузером. Стоит, поменять какое либо значение в консоли браузера и задний текст пропадает, до следующего обновления страницы.

Comment: Opera 32 - такой же эффект как на IE10.

Comment: Может попробовать так?: прописать в коде слайдера, что при выборе активного слайда, ждем сколько-то миллисекунд (пока браузер все не отобразит) а потом дописываем -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; Как это сделать на jsquery? Можете скинуть пример кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решили пока проблему простым добавлением фона.

```
background: rgba(255,255,255, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно сделать

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {

                $('#submit_name').bind('blur', function()
                {
                    $('#submit_name-desc').removeClass('cls1').addClass('cls2');
                });

                $('#submit_name').bind('focus', function()
                {
                    $('#submit_name-desc').removeClass('cls2').addClass('cls1');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Как переделать этот код чтоб, при фокусе на конкретный объект, скрипт ждал пару мс а потом подставлял значение -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; ?